# Is it ok to use the "use"-statement in non-class PHP files?

Tags: php, namespaces

the title says it all. Is it ok to do something like:

```
<?php

use Some\Very\Long\Namespace\SomeClassName;

SomeClassName::someMethod();
```

Or does this somehow negatively affect the class loader?

Comment: functions can be namespaced as well, so `use` isn't simply restricted to classes and class files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All `use` does is *alias* a long namespaced name to a different (shorter) local name. Your code is exactly equivalent to:

```
Some\Very\Long\Namespace\SomeClassName::someMethod();
```

So yes, it's perfectly fine.